# HTTP POST request using boost::asio

Tags: c++, http, boost, boost-asio

Where can I see an example of HTTP POST request using boost::asio?

I've only saw some examples with HTTP GET requests.

Comment: It would be nice to link the tutorial, so we can look in to it. In this example http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp
It seems like you write the http request yourself, so you can write POST instead of GET. 
Check out how http requests are formed and how you append parameters/arguments to your post request and so on.

Comment: Look for C++ REST SDK. Is a C++ framework for REST service the http protocol is arleady implemented. http://casablanca.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Look at this http request header for example:

```
POST /path/script.cgi HTTP/1.0
From: test@tests.com
User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 32

argument1=text&argument2=arg2text
```

Check out the get example and change the request to this. Probably alter whatever you think should be altered

Comment: How can I add arguments to the POST request?

Comment: append them to your request string. Look at the last line of the example, i gave you...